# Excel function for averaging over an increment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have a large table in excel with Column A running from 0 to 120 with increments of ~0.08 (This puts the last cell at 1441). I need to condense the table into increments of just 1. I need a function that can average the values from 0-1 and then be able to drag that function down so that the next cell references the next ~12 cells after the first. For Example: I need to average values from A1:A12, then when I drag the formula down 1 cell, it averages A13:A25, and so one.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzv5R.png)

Comment: So you would expect to have the same value output 12 times for each grouping? Also, does the data really start at row 1 or does it start at row 2?

Comment: @urdearboy I do not want the data to output 12 times. The data starts in Column B2. Row 1 is just headers. Column A contains Time (hr) with 0.08 increments starting at 0 going to 120. I am creating a new data table that increments with 1, so taking average of 0 to 1 and placing it at 0, then average from 1-2 and placing at 1.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1,12*(ROW()-1),0,12,1))
```

**ADDED IN RESPONSE TO SAMPLE DATA**

In cell `H2` to get averages of column `B` you can use the formula

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($B$1,12*(ROW()-2)+1,0,12,1))
```

In cell `I2` to get averages of column `C` you can use the formula

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($C$1,12*(ROW()-2)+1,0,12,1))
```

And so forth.

Comment: This does not give me the correct output after double checking.

Comment: I assumed that the data started in row 1. If the data starts in cell B2 then change $A$1 to $B$2, and adjust `12*(ROW()-1)` to `12*(ROW()-1)+S-1` where `S` is the start row.

Comment: This is much closer; however, still not correctly averaging.

Comment: This answer seems correct. Please show sample data (e.g. the first 24 datapoints) and the expected output in the desired cells.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I have attached the image of the sample data. The real data is much larger. I am looking for a formula to start at B2 and average B2 through B13. Then from B14 to B25. Then able to simply drag that formula down and across to fill the following columns.